# Item from Database.GetItem gets NullReference exception in field HasClones and in FieldRenderer.Render in test

Tags: unit-testing, field

I am trying to set up a simple test project to initially assert that my local C# models correspond to my Sitecore templates. The Item retrieval is successful using `Database.GetItem(itemPath)` and I can inspect the item by debugging the test and can confirm that all `Item.Fields` are present and contain the correct data. The field `Item.HasClones` however contains an error:

```
'item.HasClones' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
```

I have debugged the same Item when running the live application and then HasClones is just `false` so this only happens when getting the item in the test project.

When I attempt to read text from one of the fields using the `FieldRenderer.Render` method it results in a System.NullReferenceException. I can access the text in the same field using `item.Fields["Title"].Value.ToString();` without issue though.

I have tried getting around security using the `SecurityDisabler` in case HasClones was somehow protected but no luck. I am not sure these two errors are connected but I have no idea how to confirm it. Have I missed something in the Context configuration or something like that? The same code runs fine in the main project (where Item is accessed using `RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item` instead of with `GetItem`) so does something else need initiating that I have missed?

Test code:

```
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        State.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath = TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory;
        Context.SetLanguage(Language.Parse("sv-SE"), true);

        this.masterDb = Factory.GetDatabase("master");
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetSomeBlockData_GetDataFromSitecore()
    {
        Item item;
        string titleText;

        using (new SecurityDisabler())
        {
            item = masterDb.GetItem("/sitecore/content/TestBlock");

            bool hasClones = item.HasClones; // System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.


            titleTextOk = item.Fields["Title"].Value.ToString(); // This works fine
            titleTextBroken = FieldRenderer.Render(item, "Title"); // System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        }
    }
```

I am running: Sitecore.NET 8.2.170407, the project is using .NET 4.5.2. Testing framework is Nunit.

All the best //VA

EDIT:

I have investigated further and found that the issue with the `FieldRenderer.Render` is that in the Render method it uses the class `RenderFieldArgs` which in turn tries to check `Context.Site.DisableWebEditEditing` when initiated. Context.Site is null so the method fails. I have tried to get Context working, mostly by following [this guide](https://getfishtank.ca/blog/unit-testing-in-sitecore-with-context-and-app-config) but I can't get it working.

Comment: Hi, 
Have you tried Sitecore.FakeDb to mock your Sitecore items? 
https://github.com/sshushliapin/Sitecore.FakeDb

Comment: @ÁrvaiMihály yes I have looked at FakeDb and might be using it for some tests as well but in this case I want to confirm what is actually in the Sitecore DB. By using FakeDb I feel that I would just be testing that my constructed FakeDb items were correct, not my real Sitecore items :)

Comment: You don't wanna do this. Just saying. Every time you make a change in your Sitecore structure, you need to make a change in your code structure, which will necessitate a change in your "unit" test. What good is a test then? :D

Comment: @MarkCassidy that is exactly why I want to do this, because there are several people working on this project. If one of them changes the Sitecore structure without fixing the code structure I want to find that out when running the tests, not when the code is deployed and no text shows up (or worse) because someone decided to change a field name in Sitecore. So the tests will make sure that Sitecore and code structure are in sync, just like if we were testing an integration with an API for example.

Comment: Personally I think a unit test should not have any dependency on external resources. If you still want to validate item structure/item fields, I would go with some integration tests, querying items from a Sitecore instance via Item WebApi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to the issue, the problem in my case was that I had not set a site using `Context.SetActiveSite("website");`.

The following code works in my case:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Configuration;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Globalization;

namespace Testclass
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class MyTests
    {
        private Database masterDb;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            State.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath = TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory;
            Context.SetActiveSite("website");
            Context.SetLanguage(Language.Parse("sv-SE"), true);

            this.masterDb = Factory.GetDatabase("master");
        }

        [Test]
        public void GetItemDataFromSitecore()
        {
            Item item = masterDb.GetItem("/sitecore/Content/TestItem");
            MyItemModel data = new MyItemRepository().GetData(item);

            Assert.That(data.Title.ToString(), Is.EqualTo("My Title"));
        }
    }
}
```